# Como buscar Key de um Map, sendo que a Key do Map é do tipo Lista em Dart?

Tags: lista, flutter, dart, map

Tenho o seguinte Map:

```
Map<List<int>, String> animais;
  

animais = {
    [01, 04]: 'Avestruz',
    [05, 08]: 'Águia',
    [09, 12]: 'Burro',
    [13, 16]: 'Borboleta',
    [17, 20]: 'Cachorro',
    [21, 24]: 'Cabra',
    [25, 28]: 'Carneiro',
    [29, 32]: 'Camelo',
    [33, 36]: 'Cobra',
    [37, 40]: 'Coelho',
    [41, 44]: 'Cavalo',
    [45, 48]: 'Elefante',
    [49, 52]: 'Galo',
    [53, 56]: 'gato',
    [56, 59]: 'Jacaré',
    [60, 63]: 'Leão',
    [64, 67]: 'Macaco',
    [68, 71]: 'Porco',
    [72, 75]: 'Pavão',
    [76, 79]: 'Peru',
    [80, 84]: 'Touro',
    [85, 88]: 'Tigre',
    [89, 92]: 'Urso',
    [93, 96]: 'Veado',
    [97, 100]: 'Vaca',
  };
```

Eu quero verificar se os números que eu passar como parâmetro de busca existe na Lista de qualquer key desse Map, e pegar o value dela.

Exemplo: Passar o número 04 e buscar a key que tenha esse número na lista. Caso desse certo ele iria me retornar o "Avestruz", já que na lista de sua key há o número 04

Já tentei utilizar os métodos de busca padrão do Map mas não da certo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É algo relativamente simples, você pode utilizar a propriedade [entries](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.0/dart-core/Map/entries.html) de um `Map`, que retorna a lista de `MapEntry` que o map contém, repare na função `valueByKey()` abaixo:

```dart
const animais = <List<int>, String>{
  [80, 84]: 'Touro',
  [85, 88]: 'Tigre',
  [89, 92]: 'Urso',
  [93, 96]: 'Veado',
  [97, 100]: 'Vaca',
};

String? valueByKey(int key) {
  for (final entry in animais.entries) {
    if (entry.key.contains(key)) return entry.value;
  }
}

void main() {
  print(valueByKey(42)); // > null
  print(valueByKey(80)); // > Touro
  print(valueByKey(154)); // > null
}
```

Cada `MapEntry` do mapa representa um valor que ele contém (com sua respectiva key/value), na sua `key` vai conter a lista. Então basta verificar se a lista contém o valor. Adapte o código para suas necessidades.

Rodar no [Dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=2ea4c67e59cf93484261dc80d8b8a506&null_safety=true).

**------------ EDIT -------------**

Bom, embora na pergunta não esteja claro que a lista seja um range de valores, e que deve retornar valores dentro deste range. Segue abaixo a função para retornar valores no range, se esta for a necessidade:

```dart
String? valueByKeyInRange(int key) {
  for (final entry in animais.entries) {
    final first = entry.key.first;
    final last = entry.key.last;
    
    if (key >= first && key <= last) return entry.value;
  }
}

void main() {
  print(valueByKeyInRange(42)); // > Cavalo
  print(valueByKeyInRange(81)); // > Touro
  print(valueByKeyInRange(154)); // > null
}
```

Comment: @AugustoVasques eu também pensei nessa possibilidade. Acontece que ele foi bastante claro ao dizer "Passar o número 04 e buscar a key que tenha esse número na lista". Em nenhum momento ele especificou que o valor pode estar dentro do range dos números da lista, e nem que essa lista da key é um range de valores. Negativar por conta disso não faz sentido, é falta de interpretação.

Comment: @AugustoVasques de qualquer forma, a resposta está editada com as duas possibilidades.

Comment: Agora sim a resposta é útil pois cobre toda ambiguidade da pergunta.

Comment: Realmente eu iria precisar saber se o numero está dentro desse range, não coloquei porque iria "dar meus pulo". Mas muito obrigado mesmo. Eu ja tinha tentado de tudo e não tinha conseguido